# How can I make a subclass of NSInputStream?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I'd like to make a subclass of NSInputStream. Simply, I tried to code just like the following,

```
@interface SeekableInputStream : NSInputStream
{
    NSUInteger startOffset;
    NSUInteger totalReadLen;
}

- (NSInteger)read:(uint8_t *)buffer maxLength:(NSUInteger)len;
- (BOOL)getBuffer:(uint8_t **)buffer length:(NSUInteger *)len;
- (BOOL)hasBytesAvailable;
- (void)open:(NSUInteger)offset;

@end
```

and, I used the class like the following.

```
SeekableInputStream *stm = [[SeekableInputStream alloc] initWithURL:url];
```

Then, in runtime, I could meet the following error message.

**-[SeekableInputStream initWithURL:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10018ff30**

I didn't override initWithURL for using parent's method purposely.
Based on my knowledge, derived class can uses method of parent class, isn't it?

Can not an extension method like initWithURL be inherited?

Is there anybody inform me how to do subclassing of NSInputStream?

Comment: Have you tried (just to try) to actually reimplement method `initWithURL`?

Comment: @Saphrosit Do you mean 'reimplement' as 'override'? If yes, I can say yes. I overrided initWithURL method, but, [super initWithURL] call is failed since super instance has not the method.

Comment: It may be that NSInputStream is "special" somehow, but I'd more strongly suspect that you've got something fouled up somewhere.  Eg, you're not really including that version of your H file in the M file.

Comment: Why do you need to subclass NSInputStream?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From NSStream.h

```
// NSStream is an abstract class encapsulating the common API to NSInputStream and NSOutputStream.
// Subclassers of NSInputStream and NSOutputStream must also implement these methods.
@interface NSStream : NSObject
- (void)open;
- (void)close;

- (id <NSStreamDelegate>)delegate;
- (void)setDelegate:(id <NSStreamDelegate>)delegate;
 // By default, a stream is its own delegate, and subclassers of NSInputStream and NSOutputStream must maintain this contract. [someStream setDelegate:nil] must restore this behavior. As usual, delegates are not retained.

- (id)propertyForKey:(NSString *)key;
- (BOOL)setProperty:(id)property forKey:(NSString *)key;

- (void)scheduleInRunLoop:(NSRunLoop *)aRunLoop forMode:(NSString *)mode;
- (void)removeFromRunLoop:(NSRunLoop *)aRunLoop forMode:(NSString *)mode;

- (NSStreamStatus)streamStatus;
- (NSError *)streamError;
@end

// NSInputStream is an abstract class representing the base functionality of a read stream.
// Subclassers are required to implement these methods.
@interface NSInputStream : NSStream
- (NSInteger)read:(uint8_t *)buffer maxLength:(NSUInteger)len;
// reads up to length bytes into the supplied buffer, which must be at least of size len. Returns the actual number of bytes read.

- (BOOL)getBuffer:(uint8_t **)buffer length:(NSUInteger *)len;
// returns in O(1) a pointer to the buffer in 'buffer' and by reference in 'len' how many bytes are available. This buffer is only valid until the next stream operation. Subclassers may return NO for this if it is not appropriate for the stream type. This may return NO if the buffer is not available.

- (BOOL)hasBytesAvailable;
// returns YES if the stream has bytes available or if it impossible to tell without actually doing the read.
@end
```

As you can see, there are no initWithURL function. So, your `super` do not work, because it really don't exist. Like MrTJ says, it is a category class. It is defined in:

```
// The NSInputStreamExtensions category contains additional initializers and convenience routines for dealing with NSInputStreams.
@interface NSInputStream (NSInputStreamExtensions)
- (id)initWithURL:(NSURL *)url NS_AVAILABLE(10_6, 4_0);
```

So, I think if you use it in your subclass, it can work.

```
#import <Foundation/NSStream.h>
```

You need to import the category. Remember you CAN'T subclass a category, just overwrite it and can't call then (or if can, I don't know how)

Comment: CFStreamCreateBoundPair is supposed to be safer than trying to subclass NSInputStream and override private APIs[1]. However, AFNetworking had issues with this, so unfortunately, private API overrides are the best solution for now[2].


  [1]: http://osdir.com/ml/general/2012-02/msg08594.html
  [2]: https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/pull/1044

Comment: @HeathBorders CFStreamCreateBoundPair may be useful in solving other problems, but whether it's useful to the OPs problem is not sure. And IMHO, the way AFNetworking is implementing its subclass, is not only wrong, the implementors are also walking over very, very thin ice, especially since there is an implementation which works without  issues and does not use private APIs, which Apple can refuse any time.

Comment: If you read the thread, I linked, they did try it and ran into bugs. I agree that they should stick to public APIs, but ultimately working code wins.

Comment: I have to agree with Heath Borders. In my case using CFStreamCreateBoundPair perfectly replaced the NSInputStream subclassing. I used it to write http stream to NSURLConnection

Comment: @AlexeyKozhanov How did you use it? I just tested yesterday and CFStreamCreateBoundPair is definitely broken, in that if you schedule the stream on a runloop without opening it, it complains about sending events without being open. The bound pair is using "are you scheduled?" as the criteria for sending the event instead of using "are you open?"

Answer (score 0):

If you check out NSStream.h in the SDK, `initWithURL` is defined not in the core class `NSInputStream` but in a category called `NSInputStreamExtensions`. I don't know much about calling methods defined in a category of a base class from an inherited class, but this definitely can be the cause of the visibility problem you experience.